# How to create a set by loop over a nested map

Tags: terraform

I have a map that I want to read in locals and generate a new map from. One field in the new map will be a set containing the values from the nested data structure. I can't figure out the syntax to do this.

```
//I want to generate a set of all zones from the nested zone fields
variable "my_var" {
  type = object({
    name = string
    google_bigtable_clusters    = any
  })
  default = {
    app_name = "sdfsdfds"
    instances = {
      instance01 = [
        {
          zone = "asia-east1-a"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
        {
          zone = "asia-east1-b"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
        {
          zone = "asia-east1-c"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
        {
          zone = "asia-east2-a"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
      ],
      instance02 = [
        {
          zone = "europe-west2-a"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
        {
          zone = "europe-west2-b"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
        {
          zone = "europe-west2-c"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
        {
          zone = "europe-west3-a"
          num_nodes = 1
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This throws `The key expression produced an invalid result: string required.`

```
// locals
new_map = {
    some_field = "arbitrary string"
    set_of_zones = {
        for item in var.my_var.instances : item => {
          for subitem in item : subitem.zone => {
            zone = subitem.zone
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to get the key name but that didn't work: `for item in var.my_var.instances : item.key => {`

### Edit

I was able to do this but I don't understand why I don't have access to the key name here. I want to use the `instance01`, `instance02`, etc key name here: `for item in var.my_var.instances : item[0].zone => {`.

Comment: " I was able to do this" - so the code in the question has been updated to relfect the working version?

Comment: A quick reminder that your posts still need a spell-check before submission. This is becoming a long-standing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `type` for your variable is all messed up. You have:

```
type = object({
  name = string
  google_bigtable_clusters    = any
})
```

This means that Terraform will accept a value for the variable **only** if it has these two fields: `name` (a string) and `google_bigtable_clusters` (can be anything).

Your default value has neither of these fields. Instead, it only contains `app_name` and `instances`, so that's likely the cause of the first issue.

Regarding why you can't access the key name in your `for` loop, you need to specify both the key and value:

```
set_of_zones = {
  for key, val in var.my_var.instances : 
    key => {
      for subval in val: 
        subval.zone => {
          zone = subval.zone
        }
    }
}
```

This is a really odd thing to want to do though, because you're going to end up with a map that looks like:

```
set_of_zones = {
  instance01 = {
    "asia-east1-a" => {
      zone = "asia-east1-a"
    }
  }
}
```

Which doesn't seem super helpful since there is only one attribute in each map, and that attribute's value is the same as the key for that map.