# for k, v loop with filtering on a multi-level map

Tags: terraform

I have the following nested map:

```
node_hosts = {
  z-ca-arc-control1 = {
    name          = "z-ca-arc-control1"
    compute_node  = false
    etcd_instance = "etcd1"
    ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.01"
  },
  z-ca-arc-control2 =  {
    name          = "z-ca-arc-control2"
    compute_node  = false
    etcd_instance = "etcd2"
    ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.02"
  },
  .
  .
  etc
  .
  .
}
```

I use the `for key, value` syntax in a locals block to dereference this, i.e.:

```
locals {
   all_nodes_verbose_etcd = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               format("%s ip=%s etcd_instance=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address, v.etcd_instance)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]

   all_nodes_verbose      = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               format("%s ip=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) == 0]

   master_nodes           = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               v.name
                               if v.compute_node != true]

   etcd_nodes             = [for k, v in var.node_hosts:
                               v.name
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]

   all_nodes              = values(var.node_hosts)[*].name

   kubernetes_conf_file = format("%s/kubespray/inventory/%s/group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml", pathexpand("~"), var.kubespray_inventory)
   kubespray_inv_file   = format("%s/kubespray/inventory/%s/inventory.ini", pathexpand("~"), var.kubespray_inventory)
   context_artifact     = format("%s/kubespray/inventory/%s/artifacts/admin.conf", pathexpand("~"), var.kubespray_inventory)
}
```

I now want to add an extra level to the nested map such that it looks like this:

```
node_hosts = {
  dev = {
    z-dev-control1 = {
      name          = "z-dev-control1"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd1"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.345.01"
    },
    z-dev-control2 =  {
      name          = "z-dev-control2"
      compute_node  = false
      etcd_instance = "etcd2"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.02"
    },
  },
  prd = {
    z-prd-compute1 = {
      name          = "z-prd-compute1"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = "etcd3"
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.03"
    },
    z-ca-arc-compute2 = {
      name          = "z-prd-compute2"
      compute_node  = true
      etcd_instance = ""
      ipv4_address  = "10.123.456.04"
    }
  }
}
```

I can use the `for key, value` syntax to filter at the value level, however, if I want to
only iterate through values for dev or prd, is this possible using `for key, value` or am I now going into the realms of having to use nested foreach statements ?, my aim is extract the attributes at the bottommost object level into lists.

Looking at a different question/answer it looks like this might be possible in part using a for loop ([How to create a set by loop over a nested map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445703/how-to-create-a-set-by-loop-over-a-nested-map)):

```
set_of_zones = {
  for key, val in var.my_var.instances : 
    key => {
      for subval in val: 
        subval.zone => {
          zone = subval.zone
        }
    }
}
```

but how do I filter at the first level of my map ?.

Comment: What `set_of_zones` should look like after your transformation?

Comment: The last code excerpt was an example of a nested for, taking my node_hosts variable that contains dev and prod, I want to be able to obtain the values of name, compute_node, etcd_instance and ip4_address for dev or prod.

Comment: Sadly its not clear what your last code is doing as `var.my_var.instances` is not defined.

Comment: @Marcin ignore the last piece of code, what I want to do is to obtain all the attributes at the object level, name, compute_node etc for either dev or prod - for the last node_hosts variable in the question

Comment: Normally you would do `var.node_hosts["prd"]` for instance. Its not clear what do you really want to accomplish.

Comment: How did it go? Was `var.node_hosts["prd"]`  what you were looking for?

Comment: I think this is the answer I am after, please supply this as an answer and I will mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

To access setting for different environments (`dev`, `prd`) you can do, for example:

```
var.node_hosts["prd"]
```